# Alternative way to phrase ‘will have to have had’

Tags: word-usage

I'm sending a letter to a tenant who is moving out of our factory at a snails pace and I'm basically demanding (in a nice way) she and all her stock, furniture etc be moved by a certain date.  I have this:

> This simply means, you will have to have completed the clearance of all your possessions by Monday 8th August.

It's hurting my head, my brain is frozen and I cannot find an alternative.

Comment: Instead of _will have to have completed_, try _must have completed_.

Comment: Why is it hurting your head? It's perfectly grammatical. Why exactly are you looking for alternatives, and what kind of alternatives?

Comment: My sympathies.  You want to be absolutely clear and you want to be nice.  That is often hard.  Use John Lawler's wording.  It's nice enough.

Answer (score 2):

> This simply means (that) clearance of all your possessions **must be completed** by Monday, August 8th.

(Alternative)

> This simply means (that) all your possessions **must be removed** by Monday, August 8th.

Simpler is (usually) better.

Answer (score 0):

All of the following will work:

- you have to complete the clearance
- you must have completed the clearance
- you must complete the clearance
- the clearance must be completed